# code that generates numbers from the Poisson distribution for small lambdas

Tags: r, poisson

Why this code only works for small lambda values ? I don't quite understand why it breaks down for large ones

```
poisson_numbers <- function(lambda, n) {
  x <- numeric(n)
  U <- runif(n, 0, 1)
  print(U)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    i <- 0
    p <- exp(-lambda)
    suma <- p
    while (suma < U[j]) {
      i <- i + 1
      p <- p * lambda / i
      suma <- suma + p
    }
    x[j] <- i
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: infinite loop occurs when lambda is large because `p` is 0, and therefore `suma` is always less than `U[j]`

Comment: The Wikipedia has [stable algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Random_variate_generation).

Comment: Your function will not work for any value of lambda greater than 745.1332191019411652, because `exp(-745.1332191019411652)` is the smallest non-zero number than can be represented by floating point math in R. If lambda is any higher than this, R will evaluate `exp(-lambda)` as 0, and you will get the infinite loop described by @langtang

Comment: You could jump into `gmp` but that's certainly not going to lead to code that executes quickly.

Comment: further,  CRAN hosts packages `poisson` and  `poissonbinomial` , among others, that will do what you want far better.

Comment: if you want to fix this example (again, there are much better ways to do this, if you're doing it for real and not for pedagogy), you can also do a lot of these cases in 'log space' - e.g. see https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DPQ/html/logspace.add.html